# use laplace transformation to solve $y^{(4)}-16y=0$, being $y(0)=1$, $y'(0)=0$, $y''(0)=0$, $y'''(0)=0$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, laplace-transform

Folowing the process, I came to $$Y=\frac{s^3}{s^4-16}$$

However, when trying to write the fraction as a sum of other fractions,the system is undetermined.

$$\frac{s^3}{s^4-16}=\frac{A}{(s-2)}+\frac{B}{(s+2)}+\frac{Cs+D}{(s^2+4)}$$

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know, but your ansatz for the partial fraction is correct. I get $A=1/4$, $B=1/4$, $C=1/2$ and $D=0$. (I also get $Y(s)=s^3/(s^4-16)$. So I think you are on the right way...

Comment: @mickep I got $s^3=s^3(A+B+C)+s^2(2A-2B+D)+s(4A+4B+4C)+(8A-8B+4D)$

Comment: That is not correct, so maybe you can update your question, with the calculation leading to that equation.

Comment: Oh... got it! changed a + by a - in the midle. thanks

Comment: Fine, then maybe this question should be closed? I dont know about the rules, but I cannot see anyone else gaining something from what is left here now :)